# Google maps autocomplete, strict bounds with bounding box and custom UI

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an input that I want to work as a google maps autocomplete search, but with some custom UI (making the standard Autocomplete-widget (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Autocomplete) unusable). The standard widget lets me specify a bounding box to fetch results from and to specify that only results found in that box will be considered, by specifying `strictBounds`. The normal behaviour is to prioritise results from inside the bounding box, but this will not work for me, so `strictBounds` is crucial.

As the Autocomplete-widget does not suit my UI, I have tried to implement my own UI, using the AutocompleteService (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#place_autocomplete_service). This works fine, except that there is no way of specifying the `strictBounds` using the service.

After some more digging I found that you can call the API directly (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#location_restrict). While seeming a little unnecessarily complex, it did solve the problem of not being able to specify `strictBounds`. Unfortunately this has the problem of only accepting bounds in the form of a center point and a radius, not using a bounding box.

So my question is this: what's a good way to achieve autocomplete, in a bounding box (and only that box) with a custom UI?

Comment: I submitted this as a feature request a while ago, you can track the issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36219203