# Why property "radius" don't work getPlacePredictions google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use `getPlacePredictions` for get result autocomplete google maps. I use center map in Moscow. And I read documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompletionRequest

I see `radius` type number and specified in meters (50000). But I get results on distance 650000. Example I keyup "Sara" and get result "Saransk, Россия". My location - is Moscow. The distance is 650 000 meters beetwen Moscow and Saransk.

Example my code: https://jsfiddle.net/bg479gna/33/

```
const autoComplete = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
const input = document.querySelector('#search');
const result = document.querySelector('#result');
const getPlaceAutocomplete = (value) => {
  autoComplete.getPlacePredictions({
    input: value,
    location: new google.maps.LatLng(55.755826, 37.617300), //Moscow
    radius: 50000, //this value 50km. But i get cities on distance 650km. WHY?!?!
    componentRestrictions: {
      country: 'ru',
    },
  }, (data) => {
    data.forEach((item) => {
        result.innerHTML += `<li>${item.description}</li>`
    });
  });
};

input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    const value = input.value;

    getPlaceAutocomplete(value)
});
```

How can I solve this problem?

And I try to use `getQueryPredictions` and `getPredictions` instead `getPlacePredictions` but I get the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will can `strictBounds` parametrs. But `AutocompleteService` is not support. More [info.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42675334/google-maps-autocomplete-strict-bounds-with-bounding-box-and-custom-ui)

And [here.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36219203)

Answer (score 2):

It is only a bias, not a strict restriction.  From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/#AutocompletionRequest) you refer to (emphasis mine):

> **location** Type:  LatLng
>   ***Location for prediction biasing. Predictions will be biased towards the given location and radius.*** Alternatively, bounds can be used.
>   **radius** Type:  number
>   The radius of the area used for prediction biasing. The radius is specified in meters, and must always be accompanied by a location property. Alternatively, bounds can be used.

Comment: "Location for prediction biasing. Predictions will be biased towards the given location and radius" - and send me result from other point of planet? No. It is must to work. I think mt code to need correct...

Answer (score 0):

For now, we can set only bounds with locations.
And yo have 2 ways:

1. use `setLocationBias` - results from this area will be first
2. use `setLocationRestriction` - to find results ONLY from this area

For example:

```
FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.builder()
  .setLocationRestriction(
     RectangularBounds.newInstance(
        LatLng(
           coordinates.latitude - 0.001,
           coordinates.longitude - 0.001
        ),
        LatLng(
           coordinates.latitude + 0.001,
           coordinates.longitude + 0.001
        )
    )
)
                .setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.ADDRESS)
                .setSessionToken(token)
                .setQuery(constraint.toString())
                .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

bit late but if you are someone looking for a solution as I was ¯_(ツ)_/¯

bounds, location, and radius are deprecated on May 2023 instead we can use **locationBias** and **locationRestriction** refer this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service#AutocompletionRequest.locationRestriction

Worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

If you'd like to set `strict` restrictions per country you'll need `google.maps.places.ComponentRestrictions` See [AutoCompleteService Class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/#AutocompleteService) & [AutoCompleteService Request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/#ComponentRestrictions) .

See [Component Filtering/Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/#ComponentRestrictions) & [Country Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1#Current_codes).

Hope this helps!

Comment: OP didn't ask about restricting results to a specific country. Further to that, he is already using `componentRestrictions` in his question code.